# Combining regular expression to read text in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to read a text and create a list based on different ACTs and SCENEs. The text looks like:

```
ACT I. SCENE 1

On a ship at sea; a tempestuous noise of thunder and lightning
heard

SCENE 2

The Island. Before PROSPERO'S cell

ACT II. SCENE 1

Another part of the island

Enter ALONSO, SEBASTIAN, ANTONIO, GONZALO, ADRIAN, FRANCISCO, and
OTHERS

ACT III. SCENE 1

Before PROSPERO'S cell

Enter FERDINAND, hearing a log

SCENE 2

Another part of the island

Enter CALIBAN, STEPHANO, and TRINCULO

ACT IV. SCENE 1

Before PROSPERO'S cell

Enter FERDINAND, hearing a log
```

I imported the text into variable 'text' and tried below code to read the ACTs first and then the respective SCENEs.

```
    Acts = re.split("(ACT [^ ]+)", text)

    acts_scene = []

    for i in Acts:
        acts_scene.extend(re.split("(SCENE [\d])", i))

    print(acts_scene)
```

The sample of the output looks like:

```
'ACT I.', ' ', 'SCENE 1', "\n\nOn a ship at sea; a tempestuous noise of thunder and lightning\nheard\n\n
```

1) Is there any way I can split the ACTs and SCENEs using just single regular expression instead of running the for loop.
2) What modification should I do to avoid the full stop(.) occurring after the roman number in ACTs 
3) Is there any regular expression to capture roman numeral with ACTs, in this case: I to IV. I already tried below codes, but they don't give desired results.

```
test = any (re.split(text) for regex in ["(ACT [^ ]+)", "(SCENE [\d])"])

test = re.split("|".join(["(ACT [^[MDCLXVI]+$])", "(SCENE [\d])"])    , text)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is your expected output exactly?

Comment: Thank you!!
I'm expecting same output but want to capture ACTs with roman numerals and SCENEs with a single regular expression. I tried some approaches like : ACT [(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})] but it only captures ACT I for all the ACTs

Comment: Hey, thank you for this. Actually I'm working on a class assignment so probably there are multiple people working on the same task. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: I've edited the expected sample output.

Comment: @jack that makes sense, ya I've seen like the same question multiple times in the last day, so I've been quite confused lol. So you're trying to extract acts, scenes and scene contents into an array?

Comment: @jack also, is there a requirement to use the `re` module? Or can you use something like `PyPi regex`?

Answer (score 0):

This shoud work.

```py
>>> act_sc_regex = re.compile(r"(ACT [MDCLXVI]+\.|SCENE [\d])")
>>> acts_scene = list(filter(lambda x : x not in ['\n', ' '], act_sc_regex.split(text)))
```

With your exemple :

```py
text = """
ACT I. SCENE 1

On a ship at sea; a tempestuous noise of thunder and lightning
heard

SCENE 2

The Island. Before PROSPERO'S cell

ACT II. SCENE 1

Another part of the island

Enter ALONSO, SEBASTIAN, ANTONIO, GONZALO, ADRIAN, FRANCISCO, and
OTHERS

ACT III. SCENE 1

Before PROSPERO'S cell

Enter FERDINAND, hearing a log

SCENE 2

Another part of the island

Enter CALIBAN, STEPHANO, and TRINCULO

ACT IV. SCENE 1

Before PROSPERO'S cell

Enter FERDINAND, hearing a log
"""
>>> print(acts_scene)
[
  'ACT I.',
  'SCENE 1',
  '\n\nOn a ship at sea; a tempestuous noise of thunder and lightning\nheard\n\n',
  'SCENE 2',
  "\n\nThe Island. Before PROSPERO'S cell\n\n",
  'ACT II.',
  'SCENE 1',
  '\n\nAnother part of the island\n\nEnter ALONSO, SEBASTIAN, ANTONIO, GONZALO, ADRIAN, FRANCISCO, and\nOTHERS\n\n',
  'ACT III.',
  'SCENE 1',
  "\n\nBefore PROSPERO'S cell\n\nEnter FERDINAND, hearing a log\n\n",
  'SCENE 2',
  '\n\nAnother part of the island\n\nEnter CALIBAN, STEPHANO, and TRINCULO\n\n',
  'ACT IV.',
  'SCENE 1',
  "\n\nBefore PROSPERO'S cell\n\nEnter FERDINAND, hearing a log\n",
]
```